# Performance Analytics error Error in na.omit.xts(x) : unsupported type

Tags: r, xts

I have a data frame "test" that looks like this. There are no N/A or inf. All days are populated with data.

```
head(test)

  businessdate    strategy 1          Strategy 2
1   2014-01-01  0.000000000          0.0000000
2   2014-01-02  0.010058520         -0.3565398
3   2014-01-03  0.000707818          0.2622737
4   2014-01-06 -0.019879142         -0.2891257
5   2014-01-07 -0.019929352         -0.2271491
6   2014-01-08  0.027108810         -0.7827856
```

When I look at the class of the those columns I see:

```
> class(test[,1])
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(test[,2])
[1] "numeric"
> class(test[,3])
[1] "numeric"
```

So I think I can turn this into an xts object and to use Performance analytics. Here I turn it into a xts:

```
test_xts<- xts(test, order.by= test[,1])
```

Now  I try to use the Performance analytics package and get an error:

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(test_xts,geometric= TRUE,cex.axis=1.5)
```

The error I get is:

```
 Error in na.omit.xts(x) : unsupported type
```

Any idea what is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

xts/zoo objects are a matrix with an index attribute. You can't mix types in a matrix. There's no need to specify the `businessdate` as the index *and* in the coredata, so do not include it in the coredata.

```
test_xts <- xts(test[,-1], order.by= test[,1])
```